# How can i export cycles materials to UNITY 3D with Correct UV

Tags: uv

[image]

Ok, I fianlly success what make uv with 2 or more materials in an object

It is fine in blender, but when i export to unity, and apply the image of texture,

the green part of texture run away from correct displacement.....
what is problem?

-------UPDATE--------

It was because of wrong Material Dimension

[image]

You must export each uv images separately.

And in Unity, add materials correctly in renderer component.

Done!

Thank you.